# Numpy list comprehension iterating over 2D array

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy, iteration

I have a bit of code that loads up a long (100k-1mil) set of lines, it has an index in the first column followed by 18 values, for a total of 19 floats per line. This all is put into a numpy array.

I need to do some simple processing on the matrix to keep the index column and get out 1s and 0s depending on conditions of whether values are positive or negative, but the criterion varies as the columns are sequential pairs of values with different reference values.

The code below goes through the columns 2-19 first by evens then odds to check the values, and then creates a temporary list to put into the array I want to have at the end.

I know there's a simpler way to do this, with list comprehension and possibly lambda, but I'm not proficient enough with this to figure it out. So I'm hoping someone can help me reduce the length of this code into something more compact. More efficient would be great too, but I know that the compact methods don't always increase efficiency. It will however help me better understand list comprehension, with and without numpy.

Sample values for reference:

```
 0.000 72.250 -158.622 86.575 -151.153 85.807 -149.803 84.285 -143.701 77.723 -160.471 96.587 -144.020 75.827 -157.071 87.629 -148.856 100.814 -140.488
10.000 56.224 -174.351 108.309 -154.148 68.564 -155.721 83.634 -132.836 75.030 -177.971 100.623 -146.616 61.856 -150.885 92.147 -150.124 91.841 -153.112
20.000 53.357 -153.537 58.190 -160.235 77.575 176.257 93.771 -150.549 77.789 -161.534 103.589 -146.363 73.623 -159.441 99.315 -129.663 92.842 -138.736
```

And here is the code snippet:

```
datain = numpy.loadtxt(testfile.txt) #load data
dataout = numpy.zeros(datain.shape) # initialize empty processing array

dataout[:, 0] = datain[:, 0] # assign time values from input data to processing array

dataarray = numpy.zeros(len(datain[0]))
phit = numpy.zeros((len(dataarray)-1)/2)
psit = numpy.zeros((len(dataarray)-1)/2)

for i in range(len(datain)):
    dataarray = numpy.copy(datain[i])
    phit[:] = dataarray[1::2]
    psit[:] = dataarray[2::2]
    temp = []
    for j in range(len(phit)):
        if(phit[j] < 0):
            temp.append(1)
        else:
            temp.append(0)
        if(psit[j] > 0):
            temp.append(1)
        else:
            temp.append(0)
    dataout[i][1:] = temp
```

Thanks in advance, I know there's a fair number of questions on these topics here; unfortunately I couldn't find one that helped me get to a solution.

Comment: The way to make this simpler, and more efficient, is not to turn your loop statements into list comprehensions, but to use NumPy as NumPy. You really need to read a tutorial on this, but some hints to get you started: `phit < 0` will give you an array of booleans that tell you which values in `phit` are less than zero. You can use booleans as integers (True is 1, False is 0), but you can also use them for indexing. If you want to force them to be integers, just set a dtype. And so on. Everything you're trying to do here can be done with vectorized array-wide operations instead of loops.

Comment: That sounds different from what I was going for, but sounds like it would give me the results I want. So you're suggesting I make the output array with a dtype=int, and use the array slices on phit and psit with conditionals to get out a straight array, that I can pass right into the appropriate slices of the output data array? Hope that sounds about right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to abarnert for pointing me in the right direction with this, the solution is pretty simple.

```
datain = numpy.loadtxt(testfile.txt) #load data
dataout = numpy.empty(datain.shape, dtype=int) # initialize empty processing array

dataout[:, 0] = datain[:, 0] # assign time values from input data to processing array

dataout[:, 1::2] = datain[:, 1::2] < 0
dataout[:, 2::2] = datain[:, 2::2] > 0
```

That's it! Much shorter, much more readable, and gets me the values I want.

Comment: If you don’t prefer scnerd’s solution to your own, remember to accept your own answer. (A lot of newcomers to Stack Overflow don’t seem to realize that’s allowed.)

Answer (score 2):

As @abarnert mentioned, the solution here is not to write better loops, but (since you're using Numpy) to not loop in Python at all by understanding how to use Numpy in more advanced ways.

What you have is a matrix like

```
[ [idx, v0a, v0b, v1a, v1b, ... ], ... ]
```

And you want a matrix that's basically

```
[ [idx, 1 if v0a < 0 else 0, 1 if v0b > 0 else 0, ... ], ... ]
```

We're going to do this in two steps: first, we'll transform the matrix slightly so that the comparisons are all the same; second, we'll apply the comparison in-place.

The only difference between how we handle "even" and "odd" columns is that one is being checked for <0, the other >0. If we modify the second group of columns by multiplying them by -1, then these comparisons both become simply <0:

```
datain[:, 2::2] *= -1
```

Now we just want to know, for every value (besides the first column), is that value <0. This is super easy:

```
datain[:, 1:] < 0
```

This returns a matrix of boolean values, where each value represents whether or not the corresponding cell in `datain[:, 1:]` was less than 0. You want these as integers, 1 for True and 0 for False; it turns out, when we assign these boolean values back into our original array (which contains floats), numpy will cast the bools into floats automatically; True will get cast to 1.0, and False will get cast to 0.0.

If you don't want to throw away your original data, simply copy it off first. Here's the complete code:

```
# If you want to preserve your old data, create a copy for us to modify
dataout = np.array(datain)
# Now assign your integer values into your data array
dataout[:, 2::2] *= -1
dataout[:, 1:] = datain[:, 1:] < 0
```

For the sample input you provided:

```
array([[   0.   ,   72.25 ,  158.622,   86.575,  151.153,   85.807,
         149.803,   84.285,  143.701,   77.723,  160.471,   96.587,
         144.02 ,   75.827,  157.071,   87.629,  148.856,  100.814,
         140.488],
       [  10.   ,   56.224,  174.351,  108.309,  154.148,   68.564,
         155.721,   83.634,  132.836,   75.03 ,  177.971,  100.623,
         146.616,   61.856,  150.885,   92.147,  150.124,   91.841,
         153.112],
       [  20.   ,   53.357,  153.537,   58.19 ,  160.235,   77.575,
        -176.257,   93.771,  150.549,   77.789,  161.534,  103.589,
         146.363,   73.623,  159.441,   99.315,  129.663,   92.842,
         138.736]])
```

This code ends up with the following final result:

```
array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,
         0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [10.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,
         0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [20.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,
         0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]])
```

Comment: That's an even more elegant solution than my own, I really like it.

Comment: Actually this is cleverer than what I was thinking, but I can’t upvote it twice. :)